# R1732: Consider using 'with' for resource-allocating operations (consider-using-with)

Tags: python, warnings, pylint

I am running pylint for bug detection in my project and stumble on this warning.
How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

suppose you are opening a file:

```py
file_handle = open("some_file.txt", "r")
...
...
file_handle.close()
```

You need to close that file manually after required task is done. If it's not closed, then resource (memory/buffer in this case) is wasted.

---

If you use `with` in above example:

```
with open("some_file.txt", "r") as file_handle:
    ...
    ...
```

there is no need to close that file. Resource de-allocation automatically happens when you use `with`.

Comment: IIRC, using `something = open("a").readlines()` should de-allocate the resource imediatelly, since it is no longer referenced? But pylint still has an issue with this

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh No, that will _not_ immediately de-allocate the resource. Even if a resource is no longer referenced, it may not be garbage-collected for some time, if ever. You should never wait until garbage collection to clean up resources. That's why you never override destructors in Python.